# Can you divide the voltage coming out the battery by the current of equivalence to get the equivalent resistance of the circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage

Suppose we have the following circuit:
[image]

I known the equivalent resistance of the circuit will be equal to

$R_{eq}=\frac{1}{(R_C+20)}+\frac{1}{(R_A+10+R_B)}$

If this is so and we know the voltage from the battery and the current at A, which is also equal to the equivalent current of the circuit, then why does

$\frac{V_{eq}}{I_{eq}}\neq\frac{1}{(R_C+20)}+\frac{1}{(R_A+10+R_B)}$

Answer (score 1):

> Can you divide the voltage coming out the battery by the current of equivalence to get the equivalent resistance of the circuit

Yes

Your two approaches disagree because the equivalent resistance of that circuit is

$$
R_{eq} = R_A + 10 + \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_B} + \frac{1}{20 + R_C}}
$$